# How do I force Virt-Manager to use the hosts' llvmpipe renderer so the guests get to use 3D acceleration?

Tags: libvirt, qemu, virt-manager, graphics

I'm using `virt-manager` and set "3D Acceleration" as per what was recommended, but I'm getting this error:

> qemu_gl_create_compile_shader: compile vertex error 0:2(10): error: GLSL ES 3.00 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, and 1.00 ES

This tells me that my GPU is too old for that, which doesn't adds up since my GPU does support OpenGL ES up to 2.0.

Anyway, I do need 3D acceleration so some guests won't get sluggy, and my best bet would be to force `virt-manager` to use the hosts' llvmpipe renderer, which allows a higher OpenGL ES support.

Anyone knows how I can do that with `virt-manager`?

PS: If this can't be done like that, I'll probably have to use an older QEMU version that had lower OpenGL ES requirements. Does anyone knows what are those QEMU versions?

All I know is that QEMU 2.5 is the very first to support VirGL ( https://docs.mesa3d.org/drivers/virgl.html ), but that wouldn't be a great idea to go that old, there must be some later versions that can still make use of OpenGL (not ES, still can't understand why, as support is worse than regular OpenGL) 2.0.

PS2: I did try to add `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1` in front of `virt-manager` and ran them in a terminal, but it did nothing.

Another thing I've noticed is changing the Spice Display's xml to the right rendernode (was set to `/dev/dri/by-path/pci-0000:01:00.0-render` ) might do the trick, so where's the correct path to llvmpipe then?